# Are tuples faster than list because they are hashable?

Tags: python, python-3.x

My teacher says that tuples are faster than lists because tuples are immutable, but I don't understand the reason.
I personally think that tuples are faster than lists because tuples are hashable and lists are not hashable.

Please tell me if I am right or wrong.

Comment: Are tuples faster than lists?

Comment: You should justify your thinking first. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: That’s not what being hashable achieves. Access to list elements is also O(1).

Comment: " As in Order to access an element from a collection that is hashable it requires constant time." That isn't what hashable means nor implies.

Comment: @JohnGordon Of course it depends on what operations you're timing, and on the implementation, and on the size of the tuple/list, and even what's in it. But in CPython 3.x, for a surprising number of simple things, just changing a list to a tuple and running otherwise identical code gives you a small speedup.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, being hashable has nothing to do with being faster.

> As in Order to access an element from a collection that is hashable it requires constant time.

You're getting thing backward. The time to look up a hashable element in a collection that uses a hash table (like a `set`) is constant. But that's about the elements being hashable, not the collection, and it's about the collection using a hash table instead of an array, and it's about looking them up by value instead of by index.

Looking up a value in an array by index—whether the value or the array is hashable or not—takes constant time. Searching an array by value takes linear time. (Unless, e.g., it's sorted and you search by bisecting.)

---

Your teacher is only partly right—but then they may have been simplifying things to avoid getting into gory details.

There are three reasons why tuples are faster than lists for some operations.

But it's worth noting that these are usually pretty small differences, and usually hard to predict.<sup>1</sup> Almost always, you just want to use whichever one makes more sense, and if you occasionally do find a bottleneck where a few % would make a difference, pull it out and `timeit` both versions and see.

---

First, there are some operations that are optimized differently for the two types. Of course this is different for different implementations and even different versions of the same implementation, but a few examples from CPython 3.7:

- When sorting a list of tuples, there's a special [`unsafe_tuple_compare`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/listobject.c#L2094) that isn't applied to lists.
- When comparing two lists for `==` or `!=`, there's a special `is` test to short-circuit the comparison, which sometimes speeds things up a lot, but otherwise slows things down a little. Benchmarking a whole mess of code showed that this was worth doing for lists, but not for tuples.

Mutability generally doesn't enter into it for these choices; it's more about how the two types are typically used (lists are often homogenously-typed but arbitrary-length, while tuples are often heterogenerously-typed and consistent-length). However, it's not *quite* irrelevant—e.g., the fact that a list can be made to contain itself (because they're mutable) and a tuple can't (because they aren't) prevents at least one minor optimization from being applied to lists.<sup>2</sup>

---

Second, two equal tuple constants in the same compilation unit can be merged into the same value. And at least CPython and PyPy usually do so. Which can speed some things up (if nothing else, you get better cache locality when there's less data to cache, but sometimes it means bigger savings, like being able to use `is` tests).

And this one *is* about mutability: the compiler is only allowed to merge equal values if it knows they're immutable.

---

Third, lists of the same size are bigger. Allocating more memory, using more cache lines, etc. slows things down a little.

And this one is also about mutability. A list has to have room to grow on the end; otherwise, calling `append` N times would take `N**2` time. But tuples don't have to `append`.

---

<sub>1. There are a handful of cases that come up often enough in certain kinds of problems that some people who deal with those problems all the time learn them and remember them. Occasionally, you'll see an answer on an optimization question on Stack Overflow where someone chimes in, "this would probably be about 3% faster with a tuple instead of a list", and they're usually right.</sub>

<sub>2. Also, I could imagine a case where a JIT compiler like the one in PyPy could speed things up better with a tuple. If you run the same code a million times in a row with the same values, you're going to get a million copies of the same answer—unless the value changes. If the value is a tuple of two objects, PyPy can add guards to see if either of those objects changes, and otherwise just reuse the last value. If it's a list of two objects, PyPy would have to add guards to the two objects and the list, which is 50% more checking. Whether this actually happens, I have no idea; every time I try to trace through how a PyPy optimizations works and generalize from there, I turn out to be wrong, and I just end up concluding that Armin Rigo is a wizard.</sub>